# Processing is acting strange with text()

Tags: java, processing

I was trying to write a program to count down the seconds/minutes until the next year, but I have already hit something super weird and I can't figure out what it is doing. Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

Calendar currentTime;
Calendar newYear;
int nextYear;

void setup() {
    size(500, 250);
    frameRate(60);
}

void draw() {
    background(255, 0, 0);
    currentTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    nextYear = currentTime.get(Calendar.YEAR) + 1;
    newYear = new GregorianCalendar(nextYear, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);
    textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);
    fill(0);
    textSize(20);
    long timeInMillis = currentTime.getTimeInMillis(); //I added this to try to fix it.
    System.out.println(timeInMillis); //Used to be System.out.println(currentTime.getTimeInMillis())
    text(timeInMillis, width/2, height/2); //Used to be text(currentTime.getTimeInMillis(), width/2, height/2)
}
```

I even tried making an actual local variable for the current millisecond time, but it didn't do anything. Here is the problem: Even though I am putting the same thing into `System.out.println()` and `text()`, the number displayed in the window stays constant the whole time. It also formats it as a decimal, even though it is a long value. When I ran the program, the text was:

```
1448569995264.000
```

However, the (last five) lines of the output were:

```
1448570028853
1448570028869
1448570028886
1448570028903
1448570028919
```

The text wouldn't change at all, and I can't figure out why.

Comment: What do you want those numbers to change into?

Comment: The number displayed should represent the current unix time, but there are two things that it is doing wrong, one, it is formatting it as a float, and two, it is not updating each frame for some reason. What makes it more odd, however, is that when I use `System.out.println()` to print out the same field, it updates every frame.

Comment: @PeadarÓDuinnín The `text()` function is a function in the Processing language. Notice the title and tag.

Comment: @KevinWorkman Ah. I only quickly looked at the Processing tag. I never realised it was a language. My bad.

Comment: if you don't know what Processing is, it is basically a language to make visual "sketches" easily. It also understands all of Java, and uses the Java syntax.

Answer (score 1):

The `text()` function isn't designed to handle `long` variables. It's only designed to handle `String`, `int`, and `float` variables. So the `text()` function is treating your `long` as a `float`. That's why you're getting the decimal places.

That's also why the number isn't changing- `float` values can only handle a certain number of significant digits, so they lose accuracy with very large values like the one you're using. As a side note, this issue can also lead to strange cases like this one:

```
float x = 123456789;
println(x == x+1); //prints true!
```

The solution is to not mix `long` values with the Processing functions. If you need to create a `String` value to pass into the `text()` function, then do that manually. The easiest way to do that might be the `String.valueOf()` function:

```
text(String.valueOf(timeInMillis), width/2, height/2);
```

There are other functions available for more specific formatting, but this will get you the basics.

Comment: I was thinking it might have something to do with this. Thanks!